# How correctly assign values to elements of Sympy Matrix, solving TypeError: 'Zero' object is not iterable or 'Float' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, matrix, typeerror, sympy

Creating matrix for derivative:

```
dydx = zeros(Size,1)
```

Creating arguments for function:

```
Size = 2
k = 3
xstartswitchpoint = Matrix([[5.], [5.]])  # y,Vy
Aklinnonlin = Matrix([[k,1],[0,-0.5]])
b2x2 = Matrix([[5.], [-3.]])
```

Function for equations system

```
def dxdt_y(Aklinnonlin, xstartswitchpoint, b2x2): 
        dydx[0,0] += xstartswitchpoint[1,0] ##y' = Vy
        dydx[1,0] += -1 * Aklinnonlin[0,0] * (xstartswitchpoint[1,0]) - 9.81  ##Vy' = -k*Vy-g
        return dydx
```

As a result we are getting typeerror, because Sympy contains values inside Matrices in special types core.numbers

```
dydx[0,0] += xstartswitchpoint[1,0] ##y' = Vy
TypeError: 'Float' object is not subscriptable
```

or

```
dydx[0,0] += sum(dydx[0,0],xstartswitchpoint[1,0]) ##y' = Vy
TypeError: 'Zero' object is not iterable
```

Matrices for method steps:

```
   k1 = zeros(Size,1)
    k2 = zeros(Size,1)
```

And computing(assigning) inside numerical method:

```
                for i, number in enumerate(range(Size)):
                    k1[i,0] = hn * dxdt(A, x, b)[i] 

                for i, number in enumerate(range(Size)): 
                    k2[i,0] = hn * dxdt(A, sum(x,k1[i,0]), b)[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any problems other than needing to put the sum args in a list:

```
>>> Size = 2
>>> k = 3
>>> xstartswitchpoint = Matrix([[5.], [5.]])  # y,Vy
>>> Aklinnonlin = Matrix([[k,1],[0,-0.5]])
>>> b2x2 = Matrix([[5.], [-3.]])
>>> dydx = zeros(Size,1)
>>> dydx
Matrix([
[0],
[0]])
>>> def dxdt_y(Aklinnonlin, xstartswitchpoint, b2x2):
...         dydx[0,0] += xstartswitchpoint[1,0]
...         dydx[1,0] += -1 * Aklinnonlin[0,0] * (xstartswitchpoint[1,0]) - 9.81
...         return dydx
...
>>> dydx[0,0] += xstartswitchpoint[1,0]
>>> dydx
Matrix([
[5.0],
[  0]])
>>> dydx[0,0] += sum( [ dydx[0,0],xstartswitchpoint[1,0] ] )  # put args in list
>>> dydx
Matrix([
[15.0],
[   0]])
```

Comment: Seems like, that not solve the problem. 
Still have:
```dydx[0,0] += sum([dydx[0,0], xstartswitchpoint[1,0]])  
# put args in list
```

TypeError: 'Float' object is not subscriptable

Comment: I suspect you have redefined `dydx` or `xstartswitchpoint` to be an element of the Matrix instead of the Matrix. Check the type of each of those e.g. `type(dydx), type(xstartswitchpoint)`. If they are not each Matrix types then look back in your code to see where you changed them.

Comment: Type says <class 'sympy.matrices.dense.MutableDenseMatrix'>.

Comment: What are the shapes of each, `dydx.shape, xstartswitchpoint.shape`?

Comment: Getting error, when trying take:
   print('Shape of argument ',xstartswitchpoint.shape())
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable

Comment: `x.shape` not `x.shape()` since `shape` is a property

Comment: Sorry. 
        print('Shape of argument ',xstartswitchpoint.shape)
        print('Shape of derivative ', dydx.shape)
Shape of argument  (2, 1)
Shape of derivative  (2, 1)

Comment: `from sympy import __version__ as v` gives v of '1.10.dev' for me. I don't see any other problems and am not sure what is wrong unless you are working with an older version.

Comment: I can't do it in your way, but I watched in IDE and it is says 1.9 is current, and 1.9 is last.

Comment: And done as

```from sympy import __version__ as v
```
Too says, 1.9.

Comment: when you start a fresh session and paste in code at https://gist.github.com/smichr/01b28d8a7506595305814cc8599e35c2 do you get the same error?

Comment: I don't know how to start session here.

Comment: try just `del dxdy, xstartswitchpopint` then paste code.

Comment: I don't see "Edit" button or something like that.

Comment: at the IDE prompt type `del dxdy, xstartswitchpoint`

Comment: I created a new file, done this code, and it works.

Comment: Seems like there is problem in mine.